# How can I write data of an object in a vector to file?

Tags: c++

So currently I have this code where I have a class Group which has a name and a vector of objects of type Student. I write the name of the group, the size of the objects in the vector which works fine but now I want to write also specific information for the objects in the vector. My current code does not give the desired outcome. Here it is:

```
class Group
{
    private:
    string name;
    vector <Student*> studentList;

    public:
    Group(void);
    Group(string s);
    void addStudent(string name,int age,int stNum);

    friend ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Group& g) {
                out << g.name << "\n";

                out << g.studentList.size() << "\n";

                for (int i=0;i<=g.studentList.size();i++) {

                  out<< g.studentList[i]->getStudentAge();
                }

                return out;
 }
```

Comment: Search for "serialization". This is a *wide* topic!

Comment: Regardless of anything else, `for (int i=0;i<=g.studentList.size();i++)` is *wrong*. It should be `for (int i=0;i<g.studentList.size();i++)`, or you'll be accessing out of bounds. Remember, a container with 5 elements have valid indices 0-4 - index 5 (the size of the container) is one past the end.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It worked after I followed your change. Thank you.